# How to get index of Array in Object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this object:

[image]

And I want to get the index of "AUG" or "JUL", for exemple...

I tried:

```
graph1.indexOf( "AUG" );
```

But it returns this error: *TypeError: undefined is not a function*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript objects are *unordered*. In a way, `AUG` **is** the index. (Unlike arrays, which are indexed numerically).

There's probably another way to achieve what you're after – you might like to start a new question explaining what it is you're trying to achieve. (I suspect it might be an array of objects – looking something like this – but of course this is a guess based on the limited information on offer):

[image]